# How can one create a PR to merge from branchA to main only if the branches are different?

Tags: github-actions

In my `.github/workflows` folder, I have a `.yaml` file with the following step:

```
      - name: create pull request
        run: gh pr create -B main -H branchA --title 'Merge branchA into main' --body 'Foo'
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Sometimes, the code in `branchA` is identical to that in `main` - in this case, the following error results:

```
pull request create failed: GraphQL: No commits between main and `branchA` (createPullRequest)
```

How can I have the PR created only if the code in `branchA` is different from that in `main`?

I have looked at [conditional actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-conditions-to-control-job-execution) and [expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions), but I still don't see a way to do this.

Comment: The PR is _already_ created only if the branches are different. If you mean you don't want the pipeline to appear to have failed if they're not, just handle the error with e.g. `|| echo 'No changes'`.

Comment: Thanks @jordansharpe. So would I update the above code to be as follows: `run: gh pr create -B main -H branchA --title 'Merge branchA into main' --body 'Foo' || echo 'No changes'`? Could you post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it if it works? Thanks.